# Is polynomial time reducibility reversible?

Tags: complexity-theory, reductions, polynomial-time

If a language $A$ is reducible to some language $B$, does it follow that $B$ is reducible to $A$?

My guess is no, it having something to do with the function $f$ in the definition of $A$ reducing to $B$ needing to be invertible.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We want to help you with your specific problems, not just do your (home-)work. However, as it is we don't know what this problem is and thus how to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594/the-return-of-the-homework-question) for a relevant discussion. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is provably not the case. Let $A$ be any non-trivial language in P (different from $\emptyset$ and $\Sigma^*$), and let $B$ be any [EXPTIME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EXPTIME)-hard language. Clearly $A$ is polytime-reducible to $B$ (since $A$ is polytime and $B$ is non-trivial; or since P$\subseteq$EXPTIME and $B$ is EXPTIME-hard), but if $B$ were polytime-reducible to $A$ then it would follow that EXPTIME=P, contradicting the time hierarchy theorem.

Comment: I see. So it boils down to a "subset but not equal"/"rectangle not square"/"injective not bijective" sort of thing. Thanks for giving an example.